# Proving that an executable running many times using shared objects is working correctly and using less memory that statically linked version

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, memory, pmap

I have a binary file for a program written in C/C++ that will be run many times on the same server (Linux CentOS 7, x64) in order to simulate a load test on a remote server.  The executable can be either statically linked (.a) or dynamically linked (.so) to the dependent libraries.

In order to run as many copies as possible we are trying to run the version that uses dynamic linking in order to share as much memory between the processes as possible, however it appears to be making no difference (if anything it is slightly worse).

For example running 9000 copies of the statically linked process uses 43gb RAM, using dynamically linked uses 48gb RAM).

Using 'pmap -XX' it would appear the shared objects are being used correctly (e.g for one of them, libPocoFoundation.so) :

```
     Address Perm   Offset Device    Inode   Size   Rss   Pss Shared_Clean Shared_Dirty Private_Clean Private_Dirty Referenced Anonymous AnonHugePages Swap KernelPageSize MMUPageSize Locked                   VmFlagsMapping
7f6a9498c000 r-xp 00000000  fd:00 26053805   1940  844  422          844            0             0             0        844         0             0    0              4           4      0       rd ex mr mw me sd  libPocoFoundation.so
7f6a94b71000 ---p 001e5000  fd:00 26053805   2044    0    0            0            0             0             0          0         0             0    0              4           4      0             mr mw me sd  libPocoFoundation.so
7f6a94d70000 r--p 001e4000  fd:00 26053805     60   60   60            0            0             0            60         32        60             0    0              4           4      0       rd mr mw me ac sd  libPocoFoundation.so
7f6a94d7f000 rw-p 001f3000  fd:00 26053805     16   16   16            0            0             0            16         16        16             0    0              4           4      0    rd wr mr mw me ac sd  libPocoFoundation.so
```

There is a significant value for Shared_Clean for the libPocoFoundation.so so I *think* this is working OK.

All the tools I can find to check free memory (meminfo.py, top, free, smem, htop) seem to roughly agree that the amount of memory used and free is the same so I'm inclined to believe the figures.

All libraries (and the executable) are compiled with -fPIC using gcc/g++ 4.9.2 (needs to be an older version as this product is compiled on very old platforms).

Can anyone possibly explain why this isn't working (or at least doesn't appear to be working) or what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: The kernel will transparently share pages for the executable between multiple instances in a CoW (Copy on Write) manner, regardless of how the libraries are linked. Using shared libraries will primarily save a bit of disk space if many different applications are linked with the same library.

Comment: Thank you Jesper - after more investigation it seems you're right and statically linked executables are shared in memory so the only benefit of a .so is reduced diskspace as you describe (which is trivial really!) and the ability to upgrade the .so without upgrading the application.